# ggplot2/ggpubr visualize significance levels for global kruskal-wallis of subsets of grouped data

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'd like to visualise my data using a bar plot with the p-value of a kruskal-wallis test displayed.

The problem's that I'd like to compare subsets of the data displayed, ie I'd like to compare the proportion of cars for which vs=0 depending on the number of gears the car has.

It's my first time using ggpubr(), and I can't figure out how to work stat_compare_means() for this purpose (if it's actually possible??).

Thanks for any help!

[image]

```
#Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(ggpubr)

#Prep data
mtcars2 <- mtcars  %>% select(gear,vs)   %>% 
  group_by(gear,vs) %>%
  summarise (n = n()) %>%
  mutate(proportion = round((n / sum(n)*100),1))

mtcars2$gear <- as.factor(mtcars2$gear)
mtcars2$vs<- as.factor(mtcars2$vs)

#Make plot
ggbarplot(mtcars2, "gear", "proportion",
          fill = "vs", color = "vs", palette = "Paired",
          label = FALSE,
          position = position_dodge(0.9))  + stat_compare_means()
```